# (Part solved) Missing line items on event invoice and confirmation email for Event (using Webform CiviCRM)

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, invoice, line-items

Drupal7 / Civi5.12
I have created a webform for event bookings, using webform_civicrm.
The webform uses Participant Fee for the exhibition cost, and a Line Item for an additional booking fee.

Can anyone guide me how to make the line item reflect on the Invoice and in the confirmation email?

UPDATE - the solution from @KarinG below fixes the invoice issue.

STILL NEED HELP WITH CONFIRMATION EMAIL
 - does not print the line item
 - has wrong sales tax amount (shows the percentage not the amount)
 - reflects Amount after tax in the "Amount Before tax' field

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this PR by Andrei (who works on the Wordpress/Caldera form integration) may help fix this (Core) issue:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13477

It removes bad logic re: participants -originally included in Core invoicing code and works great. I’ve tested it/used it myself using Drupal/Webform CiviCRM module.

Unfortunately Andrei’s PR has been deemed ‘needs work to be reviewable’ - so it has gone nowhere. And that’s unfortunate.

Comment: Thanks you @KarinG. That fixes the invoice.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with contribution receipts. In the message template I found {if $lineItem and $priceSetID and !$is_quick_config} Since the Webform CiviCRM Integretion module does not fill in the PriceSet ID fields in the table civicrm_line_item, it does not use this code to pull data for the receipts.

My fix was to remove "and $priceSetID" So it now looks like: {if $lineItem and !$is_quick_config}

Maybe it is the same for events

Comment: Thanks for the advice @iowa-boy. Unfortunately the Event template doesn't reference $priceSetID. 
I'll report back if I find the fix for the event confirmation email.
(KarinG's advice fixed the invoice problem)